# The expressive power of languages : Information content in a sentence : How do we measure it

Tags: computational-linguistics, cross-linguistic, comparative-linguistics

`What is your name`

`Isme shoma chi e`

Two sentences - same content.

My question is about the way to measure information content in a language.  How do we do this? Because quite evidently count of the number of words would be different for different languages.

Secondly are there metrics for the amount of such information a speaker conveys in unit time for a particular language? This can be based on a benchmark which uses a standard piece/pieces of information.

Comment: We don't measure information content. Sometimes we can say that one sentence contains a subset of the information of another sentence, but we don't have a meta-epistemology that allows us to enumerate information.

Comment: @user6726 but what about taking a sample text in a particular language against which other languages can be benchmarked.

Comment: There ought to be a theoretical way to measure information by scaling between totally constant signals (minimum of information) and totally random signals (maximum of information). However, how to quantify the signals, and their patterns, and their redundancy, and their algorithms, is an insoluble problem that just points out the awful truth -- that everybody learns their own language, and builds their own grammar for it, in their own way, and thus there are not, and cannot be, any standard benchmarks for even a single language. Let alone across languages.

Comment: @ARi, the problem is that you can't enumerate all of the information in "I have to leave" or "The house is cold", and say whether one has more information than the other.

Comment: If we use an ontological basis then 'The house is cold' definitely has a different amount of info than 'The first red coloured building from here houses the head quarters' @user6726

Comment: Inverse of average tongue-tip travel per hour when reading the New Testament aloud.

Comment: @GregLee Phonemes per minute is a metric though ...about 18 for English I guess.

Comment: IMO, this question is definitely in the realm of linguistics and computational linguistics. Entropy and mutual information are regularly discussed by computational linguists; information density -- not so much. I am not qualified to provide an answer to this question myself, but you may find [this paper](http://www.ddl.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/fulltext/pellegrino/pellegrino_to%20appear_language.pdf) to be of interest. If you still want me to migrate this question to cs, I will do so.